# c# - html text to rich text box

Tags: c#, html

quick explanation im making a program that receives emails then displays them and if it detects html in the email, it will convert it to how it looks on gmail or text. To do this im just looking for html tags and replacing them like below:

```
        eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine);
        eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("<b>", "\b");
        eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("</b>", "\b0");
        eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("<font color = Black>", "");
        eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("<font color = red>", "");
        eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("<font color = Maroon>", "");
        eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("<font color = blue>", "");
        eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("<font color = DarkBlue>", "");
        eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("<font color = green>", "");
        eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("<font color = grey>", "");
        eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("<font color = purple>", "");
        eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("</font>", "");
        eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("<a href =", "");
        eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("> Click here </a>", "");


        //        HtmlText = HtmlText.Replace("<font color = green>", EmailBody.SelectionColor = Color.Red);
        //      HtmlText = HtmlText.Replace("</font>", EmailBody.SelectionColor = Color.Black);

        EmailBody.Text = eHtmlText;
```

Couple things dont work, the bold tags just get replaced with these black squares with white cirlces inside instead of making the text bold if you know what i mean. The colors work except insead of just deleting them i want to actually make the text that color. I tried in the commented out lines but obviously putting that into a string wouldnt work and im not sure how else to do it. mabye a string array to split the string where it finds the tags and then seperatly add the color. any help is appriciated

Comment: My guess is the encoding is off that could be why you are getting weird symbols. (square and circle)

Comment: Even if i put "\b hi \b0" in a blank rich text box it still happens

Comment: You probably need to do `eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("</b>", @"\b0");` or `eHtmlText = eHtmlText.Replace("</b>", "\\b0");`

Comment: tried that when i started but it didnt make a difference

Comment: use the `StringBuilder` class.

Comment: i found its because im using .text instead of .rtf, still trying to get my head around it though